# Как реализовать прототип объекта javascript

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь реализовать прототип объекта таким образом:

```
var x1 = {
 self:false,
 max:true
}

var x2 = {

  self:true

}

x1.__proto__ = x2;

console.log(x2.max);
```

в итоге получаю ошибку undefined.

Когда использую такой метод, то все работает:

```
 var x1 = {
    self:false,
    max:true
 }

  var x2 = {

    self:true

   }

 x2.__proto__ = x1;

 console.log(x2.max);
```

В чем разница?

Comment: разница в предпоследней строчке кода.

Comment: Я понимаю что если забор не зеленый то у него другой цвет, но это не говорит о свойствах его краски и как работает это

Comment: Возможно вы уже вкурсне, но хочу предупредить, что использовать его следует с отсторожностью.
Почитать можно здесь: [Object.prototype.__proto__](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

Comment: Да некоторые браузеры IE его не поддерживают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если один объект имеет специальную ссылку `__proto__` на другой объект, то при чтении свойства из него, если свойство отсутствует в самом объекте, оно ищется в объекте `__proto__`.

```
x1.__proto__ = x2; // x1 наследует x2, в x2 нет свойств x1
```